# What Microsoft licenses do I need for this scenario?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019, licensing

We would like to deploy a program to multiple users via remote desktop. Now we are trying to find out what kind of licenses we would need for this. Unfortunately, none of us have a clue about Windows Server. Now I thought I'd just ask here. Maybe someone can help us out.

Here's the scenario:
We create content for the program we want to provide, which can only be opened and used by this program. We sell that content. However, we are asked now and again whether there are no test versions of our content. We don't want to send a stripped down version of the content or something like that to the potential customers. Instead, the idea was to "publish" the program along with the content via Remote Desktop. The customers would then receive a link to a remote desktop gateway (e.g., Apache Guacamole), log in there, and then view the content and test it within this remote desktop session. This should be able to access five people at the same time.

Of course, we could use five Windows 10 Pro machines, configure them, and then put them behind Apache Guacamole. However, this, of course, violates the Windows 10 EULA. So we are currently trying to figure out how to make this work with Windows Server and what we need to do to make it work.
As I understand it so far, we would need a Windows Server 2019 Essentials license as well as five RDS 2019 User CALs, correct? Or do we need more? Where is the program running that we would then like to deploy via Remote Desktop? On the Windows Server host itself, or does it require virtual machines? If so, what kind of Windows licenses would we need for the VMs? It can't be Windows 10 licenses, because they are not allowed to be used for such things.

I hope someone can help us here.

Answer (score 0):

*RDS External Connector* licenses could apply in that scenario. In addition to the Windows Server licenses, you would have to get one *RDS External Connector* license for each RDP server that external parties connect to.

As with all Microsoft licensing questions, please consult your MSP or Microsoft contact to make sure to get the proper licenses. Microsoft licensing is complex.